# Failed Update on KB2791765 for months

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, updates, windows-error-reporting

I have been trying to update this computer for months. Every time it states:

> System update KB2791765 failed. Windows_Update Code 8024200D.

Please help me to get this update taken care of. It tells me that there is an updated needed every day for months.

Comment: Have you tried downloading the update manually [from the Microsoft Catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB2791765)?

Comment: Try downloading from this link and install....https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36905